# How does AWS NLB work when it comes to routing packets?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to understand how AWS NLB routes traffic between a client and targets. I ran a simple test with NLB using tcpdump in both the client and server to see who is sending packets where etc. This is what i found from tcpdump -

NLB IP:172.31.29.2 Mac:02:4d:8f:d9:22:e2

Client IP:172.31.20.174 Mac: 02:7e:b1:06:aa:42

1. 02:7e:b1:06:aa:42 > 02:4d:8f:d9:22:e2, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 172.31.20.174.47682 > 172.31.29.2.80: Flags [S]
2. 02:4d:8f:d9:22:e2 > 02:7e:b1:06:aa:42, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 172.31.29.2.80 > 172.31.20.174.47682: Flags [S.]

Server IP:172.31.24.59 Mac: 02:0d:2c:74:be

3. 02:4d:8f:d9:22:e2 > 02:0d:2c:74:be:88, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 172.31.20.174.47682 > 172.31.24.59.http: Flags [S]
4. 02:0d:2c:74:be:88 > 02:7e:b1:06:aa:42, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 172.31.24.59.http > 172.31.20.174.47682: Flags [S.]

From #4 line above, server responded with an acknowledgement packet directly to the client - which makes me think that it is doing Direct Routing instead of sending response packets via the NLB.

But, when i look at line #2, i expected to see that the acknowledgement packet from the server IP/Mac address instead of the NLB IP/Mac address as seen in line #4. I do understand that in line #3, the mac address is of NLB but since NLB preserves client IP, we can see the client IP intact.

Would appreciate if some can explain how this routing is happening.

Answer (score 5):

The short version: Network Load Balancer isn't really a device, and VPC isn't really Ethernet, and what you see is an artifact of this otherwise-convincing illusion.

NLB is provided by an internal service called AWS Hyperplane, which is integrated with the VPC network infrastructure.  It manipulates traffic in the network at the flow level, rewriting source or destination IP addresses as the traffic passes from machine to machine.

Take two machines on the same subnet, without an NLB in the mix, and who don't have each other in their ARP tables... and ping from one to the other.  On the instance where you run the ping, you'll see ARP traffic going out to discover the other instance, and you'll see the ARP response come back from the other instance.  But on the other instance, you'll sniff... nothing, because that ARP negotiation never actually occurred end-to-end.  It only looks like it does.  The ARP response is forged by the network, including the source MAC address of the second machine.

Something similar is happening here.  The network is essentially forging the source MAC at the same time it rewrites the source IP... so the server responds "directly" to the client IP, but then the network translates both the source address and the source MAC to appear to be "from" the NLB ENI.  It gives the impression of asymmetry but that's an illusion, because the traffic isn't really going "through" the NLB in either direction.

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense, Am looking for any material on AWS Hyperplane. But, hardly finding any on the net.

Comment: AWS Hyperplane is an internal service, so they don't really say much a about it, directly... but during "Tuesday Night Live" at re:Invent 2017, Peter DeSantis talked about Hyperplane, which evolved from the S3 Load Balancer.  https://youtu.be/dfEcd3zqPOA?t=1h17m0s

Comment: There are several re:Invent videos that give a lot of insight into how VPC networking actually works.  One recent example is [NET313: Amazon VPC: Service at the Speed of Light](https://youtu.be/UP7wDBjZ37o) by Colm MacCárthaigh from re:Invent 2018.

Comment: thanks again. very useful videos. i should probably stop trying my networking experiments here. i was trying to do lvs on an ec2, but all my packets were lost somewhere.